# CakePHP: Redirect url in routes.php

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm trying to redirect an old url to a new url using routes.php

old url = www.mywebsite.com/**old_url**

new url = www.mywebsite.com/sub_folder/**old_url**

here's all the different attempts I've tried independently and all have failed:

```
Router::connect('/old_url', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'old_url'), array('pass' => array('/sub_folder/old_url')));
Router::connect('/old_url', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'old_url'));
Router::redirect('/old_url', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'old_url'));
Router::redirect('/old_url', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'old_url'), array( 'pass' => '/sub_folder/old_url'));
Router::redirect('/old_url', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'old_url'), array( 'persist' => '/sub_folder/old_url'));
```

I've looked through the book. Is this possible? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Did you moved your application from root to a subfolder ?

Comment: well, we have the ctp file in a sub_folder with same name as controller. The controller 'sub_folder' has "function old_url () { ...$this->render('old_url/old_url'); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router::connect('/old_url/*', array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'old_url'));